# Is it possible to have a Function that takes any number of variables of any type?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple function that takes a string and sends an email to me with that string (the function is used when debugging a live site)

```
public void errEmailV1(string strVars)
{
    sendEmail("me@email","emailSubject",strVars);  
}
```

Naturally to cal the function and send over multiple variables I'd:

```
Functions funcs = new Functions();
funcs.errEmailV1(someVariableThatisAString+", "+someIntVariable.ToString() +"...");
```

I later evolved my function to be able to call it faster

```
Functions funcs = new Functions();
funcs.errEmailV2(someVariableThatisAString,someIntVariable.ToString());

public void errEmailV2(params String[] paths)
{
    string strVars="";
    //a rather simplified version of the loop:
    for (int i = 0; i < paths.Length; i++)
    {
        strVars+= paths[i];
    }
    sendEmail("me@email","emailSubject",strVars);  
}
```

I doubt it is, but is it possible for my V3 to take any number of strings, ints and booleans (I rarely if ever send any other types) instead of having to always add `ToString()` ?

Comment: Um, `params object[]` just like `string.Format` uses? (Then use `string.Join` rather than your existing loop.)

Comment: I was going for Extension methods but @JonSkeet answer looks cleaner. Not surprise there:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using `params object[]` and [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Functions funcs = new Functions();
funcs.errEmailV2(someVariableThatisAString, someIntVariable);

public void errEmailV2(params object[] paths)
{
    string strVars= String.Join(", ", paths);
    sendEmail("me@email","emailSubject",strVars);  
}
```

Comment: Nice copy of Jon Skeet answer in the comment

Comment: @LiquidCore, You don't have to be Jon Skeet to suggest `params object[]`. It's pretty obvious in this case.

Comment: The more you know right, works perfectly thanks !
I can't edit your answer (as I need to ass 6 more characters) but you're missing a 3rd closing bracket on your second last line.

Comment: @LiquidCore Actually it´s not a simple copy, it´s rather the code that belongs to the comment.

Comment: @HimBromBeere oh wow you added "object" and ".ToString()"

That's some hard work there

Comment: @haim770 as i've said I would have gone for extension methods, but Jon answer was cleaner and I didn't think about it

Comment: @LiquidCore What do you want to extend here? Type `object`? Or `string`? I can´t see any advantage of using an extension-method here.

Comment: @HimBromBeere You could extend object. The only advantage is that you can pass object and call tostring. But as I said jon skeet (and your copy) it's the right way

Comment: Note that you don't need to call `Select` at all. Just `string.Join(", ", paths)` would work fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet Indeed, I always thought it was `String.Join(string, IEnumerable<string>)` while it´s actually `IEnumerable<T>`. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: A bunch of overloads were added in .NET 4.